# Facebook API: Get all likes of a post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all users that liked a post of a page. I'm setting LIMIT 200000, but it's returning 1000, and the post has 1200 likes. What are my options?

FQL:

```
select post_id, user_id
  from like 
 where post_id = "XXXXX"
  LIMIT 200000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default,Facebook Graphi API returns only the first 1000 results,Doesn't matter what your Limit Parameter is set to.

To overcome this problem,There is a paging key provided in the JSON parsed array,Something like this,

`"paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": "MzE0NzA0Njc0ODE0", 
        "before": "Nzc5NTQ3MDU1NDAyNjc4"
      }, 
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/734056698/likes?limit=25&after=MzE0NzA0Njc0ODE0"
    }`

Here,You will be needing to access the next value to get your rest 200 likes.
Regards